# GNU screen cannot find terminfo entry on HP-UX

Tags: gnu-screen, hp-ux, terminfo

I am trying to make `screen` work on `HP-UX B.11.23 U ia64 0308561483 unlimited-user license`.
Please notice I do not have root access.

I have already compiled `screen` successfully, configured with `LIBS=-lcurses`.

When I try to start screen it wrotes
`Cannot find terminfo entry for 'xterm'.`

But there ARE terminfos for the terminal type in

```
screen-4.0.3> ls -a /usr/share/lib/terminfo/x/
.         ..        x-hpterm  x1700     x1720     x1750     xitex     xl83      xterm     xterms
```

I thing the problem may be there are in non-standard path, because according to `man` page standard path is `/usr/lib/terminfo/?/*`

**What I tried:**

But as I said I do not have root access so cant make symlink, anyway I tried run screen with filled `TERMINFO_DIRS` (`TERMINFO_DIRS=/usr/share/lib/terminfo/x/ ./screen` and `TERMINFO_DIRS=/usr/share/lib/terminfo/ ./screen`) but none of them work - same error.

Change TERM to different values - same error `Cannot find terminfo entry for <WHATEVER WHAT WAS IN TERM VAR>.`

Put something into screenrc and run `./screen -c screenrc`

```
screen-4.0.3> cat screenrc
attrcolor b ".I"
term xterm
termcap xterm*  LP:hs@
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm'
defbce "on"
```

I also tried to compile it against `termcap` from `http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Development/Libraries/termcap-1.3.1/`, but it also did not work, same symptoms.

Is there anyone who has working screen on this platform and could post output of `ldd` or binary itself?

But no luck so far, have you got any suggestions? Need some additional information, let me know.
Also please see `strace` attached in comments.

Comment: Do a `strace` on `screen` and see where it stats. If possible, create a symbolic link to inform of the correct location of your terminfo for screen.

Comment: Here is `strace` http://pastebin.com/W6rYdf2A, but it does not seems to be helpfull to me, the path nor file is not mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [installation instructions](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/cgi-bin/wwwtar?/hpux/Sysadmin/screen-4.0.3/screen-4.0.3-src-11.11.tar.gz%20screen-4.0.3/HPUX.Install%20text) for screen on HPUX say

```
Note:

* Install termcap first and *then* screen. If you do it the other
  way around, screen will not work because the termcap entries will be
  missing. If you update termcap in the future, you will need to
  re-install screen afterwards of course.
```

Did you actually install termcap or did you just compile against it?

Comment: I finally make it work! I figured out, there already was some `termcap` in system but on very special place, so I had to add this path to `LDOPTS` variable and it start working, with kind of limited functionality (no colors, if I attempt to modify hardstatus colors screen aborts itselfs, but it is termcap limited capability, according to `gdb`)